# Click on individual component in a row of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview that is populated by a custom adapter. This listview has a custom layout which consists of an imageview and a textview.

What I would wanna do is when I press on that imageview from any row, it will change its UI (setAlpha) and run a background network request.

However, I couldn't figure out how to do this if the component is unique individually. When I click on the imageview from any row, only the last row will be affected. I did this all in the adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null) {
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_follows, null);
        vh.ivHeart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgHeart);
        vh.tvMerchantName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMerchantName);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    lf = arrListFollow.get(i);

    vh.tvMerchantName.setText(lf.getMerchantName());

    // only the last row affected
    vh.ivHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!lf.isFollowed()) {
                vh.ivHeart.setAlpha(1f);
                lf.setFollowed(true);
            } else {
                vh.ivHeart.setAlpha(0.3f);
                lf.setFollowed(false);
            }
        }


    });

    return view;
}
```

I think this is obvious because all of the imageviews inflated on this layout gets the same ID. So far, this is how I did it but couldn't make it work well.

How do I click on an individual component on a listview row and change its UI programmatically?

Comment: Not exactly a solution to your problem, but check out this video by Chet Hasse you should get an idea how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCHNAi9kJI4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it as using onClick `view` parameter:

```
vh.ivHeart.setTag(lf);
// only the last row affected
    vh.ivHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           YOUR_CLASS_NAME obj=(YOUR_CLASS_NAME)view.getTag();
            if (!obj.isFollowed()) {
                view.setAlpha(1f);
                obj.setFollowed(true);
            } else {
                view.setAlpha(0.3f);
                obj.setFollowed(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have many problems to resolve this problema but i find a method to correct this.

In the class thats extends of BaseAdapter 
i declare a ArrayList in the constructor of type Object like:

```
ArrayList<Object> tags = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

for what?

well the problem is that event Onclick of button or other component only know the last tag refer to last row... it is the reason for only affect the last row...

So

```
 view.setTag(holder);
             tags.add(view.getTag());
```

Here a save the tag refer to holderview

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                ComponentsHolder holder_current= (ComponentsHolder) tags.get(position); **//HERE we obtain the tag refer to correct holder of position row** 


          if(holder_current.Description.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
              holder_current.Description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          else
              holder_current.Description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           notifyDataSetChanged();

           }
          });
```